# Create Camunda user automatically wih H2 DB

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, camunda

I am using camunda springboot dependency with H2 camunda database. Everytime I run my application with embeded tomcat from Spring Boot, it redirects me to camunda user creation page.

In my application properties, I already configured a user.

```
camunda.bpm.admin-user.id=test
camunda.bpm.admin-user.password=test
```

Any idea to overcome this issue?

Edit : this issue comes when I run spring boot application from eclipse. Doesn't come when run the application from intellij..

Comment: This looks correct(I'm also using it). Are you sure the application properties are picked up? Try to set spring.config.location in the startup parameters

Comment: this issue comes when I run spring boot application from eclipse. Doesn't come when run the application from intellij..

Comment: Check the start parameters of the application. I guess you won't have `-Dspring.config.location` added in eclipse or it points to wrong file.

Comment: clean the project and then run. Eclipse sometimes dose not clean it itself when running project everytime from the toolbar run button.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure camunda admin user in bootstrap.yaml file like below, this configuration would automatically create users while process engine bootstraps.

```
camunda:
  bpm:
    enabled: true
  filter:
    create: All
  admin-user:
    id: admin
    password: admin
    email: admin@camunda.com
    first-name: Camunda
    last-name: Admin
```